# The form element still seem to render outside the form modal

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form inside the bootstrap modal, this forms is for deletion. There was no problem inside the local host, but when the site is uploaded, the form element still seems to render outside the form modal.

[image]

My code is here:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a class="button-delete btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDelet" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
           aria-controls="collapseDelet">
            delete user
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseDelet">
            <form class="row" action="{{route('user.delete',$item->id)}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                <button type="submit" class="button-accept">
                    yes
                </button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDelet" class="button-reject">
                    no
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked all the elements and no element is open and all are in their place and closed properly

Comment: Are you sure it's the same bit of code? The screenshot has "delete" instead of "delete user", and there's absolutely nothing in your form tag. Not the class, not the action, not the method.